# Yesterday's/Previous timestamp is greater than today's/Now. How to fix if?

Tags: php, date, timestamp

My question does not require including source code, it is just semantic.
I want to count number of seconds, minutes, hours, days, weeks, months and years a post has.
And by doing so, some work as expected but others are giving me a logical error by proving me the difference between dates which is negative.

Let me be clear with codes

```
//Get the questions
$query = $con->prepare("
    SELECT * FROM users, text WHERE users.user_id = text.user_id
");
$query->execute();

$today = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
while ($row = $query->fetch()) {
   $millsec = strtotime($row['date']); 
   $diff = $today - $millsec;
   echo $diff;
}
```

And I am getting some negative results which affect my entire output.
This happens on some dates not all of them.

Any way to fix this?

Comment: Without knowing the exact data, it's hard to tell. Try echo `echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s')." - {$row['date']} = {$today} - {$millsec} = {$diff}";`

Comment: Could it be that in some cases the database column `$row['date']` has a date in advance of today? Because thats the only reason that code would generate a negative number

Comment: _Small Point_ You can replace `$today = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));` with `$today = time();` In fact you could just code `$diff = time() - strtotime($row['date']);` inside your loop

Comment: Also read up on the sql JOIN syntax rather than using implied joins like `users, text`

Comment: Is the database timezone the same as the PHP timezone?

Comment: If you want the current time in PHP, just use `time()`, you don't need `strtotime()`.

Comment: Try a test with the query `SELECT NOW() AS date`

Comment: Get now() from the SQL server not the PHP server.  Even if you use UTC the clocks could differ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer for this.
My PHP time wasn't matching with my computer time.
So when I inserted data, I inserted them with My computer time and when retrieving them,
I compared it to the server's time which made wrong different.

Thank you everyone for your assistance!

Answer (score 2):

Do the time arithmetic in the database rather than PHP. This avoids problems if the clocks are not in sync or they're configured with different timezones.

```
SELECT *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t.date) AS diff
FROM users AS u
JOIN text AS t ON u.user_id = t.user_id
```

Then you can use `$row['diff']`.

Comment: Yes Database's time zone as the same the PHP's.

Comment: Have got this error: ` Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'date' in field list is ambiguous in E:\....` And I don't think the issue is about the DB. Problem is that today's/now's timestamp is being greater than yesterday's/previous one

Comment: You have a `date` field in both tables. Your original code is probably using the wrong date.